# What thickness aluminium can be cut with a scissor?

Tags: aluminum

I'm thinking of cutting some thin aluminium sheet to make some covers.  I dont have a saw or skill so as a temporary solution want to use scissors or another tool(I think there is a hand tool to cut thin metal, do you know what it is called).

Whether I go for the scissors or hand tool, what is the maximum thickness of aluminium I can expect it to cut?

Thanks.

Comment: Tin snips or a fret saw : try searching

Comment: try using scissors that you already have

Comment: The maximum  thickness would depend on the pair of scissors. How would we know that?

Comment: Scissors and metal shears tend to leave curved, sharp edges with slivers. I prefer sheet metal nibblers, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Draper-Expert-250mm-Hand-Nibbler/dp/B0001K9TGU/ref=as_li_ss_tl . The trick is that they remove a strip in the middle, so forces are uniform across the sheet.

Comment: offset aviation snips are also worth considering too (because your hand doesn't pass between the sharp edges) but if you're not in a hurry I guess the nibbler may be a cheaper option.

Comment: Some of the answer is going to be determined by how strong your hands are. If you're purchasing the aluminum, you may find it worthwhile to purchase a hacksaw to make the cuts with. They're not terribly expensive, they don't take up much space to store (if you're living in a small space), and it will make the start of a tool collection you can use to continue to DIY for the rest of your life.

Comment: I agree with drmoise I have hand nibbleRd that I can cut almost as fast as tin snips and my power nibbler is much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience snips can cut upto 2mm thickness, scissors upto 0.5mm thickness aluminium.

Sheet metal has sharp edges, there is a risk of minor cuts.

The sharp edges can be dulled using a file, stone, or the back of a knife blade etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thicker sheets can be cut by scoring with a utility knife (from both sides for thicker material), then flexed so it snaps.